# I added the "Cross" Effect strip to two text strips and it's making the background image transparent

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, text-object

I added the "Cross" effects strip to two text strips to create a fade-like transition. It worked but during the transition the background image becomes transparent.

[before the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdvWH.png)

[image: during the effect]

Comment: Not a VSE expert but I think that is expected behavior, that is how cross fading works, by varying alpha. I think you are supposed to overlap the fading strips one over the other in different channels for it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

The scene you have as the background clip is set to have a transparent background and in the sequencer preview you have enabled the alpha view.

You can turn off the scene background transparency in the render settings under Shading.

[image: shading options]

To not see the background transparency in the preview you can change to colour only display in the header.

[image: VSE preview header]

Another option is to add another strip to use as the background, this can be a simple colour effect strip to have a solid colour behind everything.

Answer (score 1):

In Compositing you need to change the *Blend mode* to *Over Drop*

Comment: Could show how to tweak these settings? Perhaps add a screenshot